# Using a parameter on the root with iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm wondering how iron-router handles using a parameter on the root.

Say I've got a handful of routes:

```
Router.route("/:uri"); // domain.tld/MyCustomUri
Router.route("/app/login"); // domain.tld/app/login
Router.route("/about"); // domain.tld/about
```

This works, but I'm wondering how iron-router parses it, and if there are any efficiency issues?

In this case is iron-router checking to see if the parameter on the root matches a route case, if not then it must be a `:uri` parameter (and therefore settles on that), or is it just hitting the routes in chronological order? What's the logic iron-router is using here?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial#anonymous-parameter-globbing) from Manuel Schoebel:

> The routes are checked in the order you created them.

Therefore in your case, `/about` would point to your `/:uri` route, with `this.params.uri == "about"`. (and your `/about` route could not be reached)

I thought I also read this rule in the official documentation as well but sadly, I cannot seem to find it back. You can find [comments](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1053#event-196538048) that support this premise though.

People are discussing [in an open issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1236) on the project's Github of the possibility to allow iron-router to "be smart" and match "static routes" *in priority* to ones with parameters, regardless of the order the routes were declared in. So I am guessing it is not the case as of today.

Comment: Given that I would put your `/:uri` route last in your router.js file since that will involve a lookup against a collection.